# Problems with adding a limited number of objects to an array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

I am currently designing a program that will take a list of names and store them into 3 different arrays, it will then add all the names into another single array in order to split them into two different teams (two other arrays) I have managed so far to get everything to add into the final two arrays properly but I have a nested IF which is supposed to stop values being added into the array after it reaches a certain length that isn't working.  I can't figure out why this IF..Else function isn't working and was just wondering if there was anyone out there with a similar problem when adding to an array using array.length
I have included a jsFiddle because there is quite a lot of code involved and I also must credit 
 http://dreaminginjavascript.wordpress.com/2008/08/22/eliminating-duplicates/ 
for their part of code which came in useful for only adding single records into the array.

http://jsfiddle.net/29q50yz0/

```
function randomFunction() {
document.getElementById("test4").innerHTML = team1.length;
if (team1.length <= 6 ) { //|| team2.length <= 5
    for (index = 0; index < tier1.length; index++) {
        randomNumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
        if (randomNumber1 <= 4) {
            team1.push(tier1[0]);

            eliminateDuplicates(team1);
            tier1.splice(0, 1);
        } else {
            team2.push(tier1[0]);

            eliminateDuplicates2(team2);
            tier1.splice(0, 1);
        }
    }

    for (index = 0; index < tier2.length; index++) {
        randomNumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
        if (randomNumber1 <= 4) {
            team1.push(tier2[0]);

            eliminateDuplicates(team1);
            tier2.splice(0, 1);
        } else {
            team2.push(tier2[0]);

            eliminateDuplicates2(team2);
            tier2.splice(0, 1);
        }
    }

    for (index = 0; index < tier3.length; index++) {
        randomNumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
        if (randomNumber1 <= 4) {
            team1.push(tier3[0]);

            eliminateDuplicates(team1);
            tier3.splice(0, 1);
        } else {
            team2.push(tier3[0]);

            eliminateDuplicates2(team2);
            tier3.splice(0, 1);
        }
    }
} else if (team1.length > 6) {
    team2.concat(tier1, tier2, tier3);
    document.getElementById("test2").innerHTML = team1;
    document.getElementById("test3").innerHTML = team2;
} else if (team2.length > 6) {
    team1.concat(tier1, tier2, tier3);
    document.getElementById("test2").innerHTML = team1;
    document.getElementById("test3").innerHTML = team2;
}
    document.getElementById("test5").innerHTML = team1.length; }
```

please note, even though there are more than 12 records I am looking for two 'teams' of six and I am looking for the code to add the remaining records into team2 when team1 reaches a length of six, I have included some test outputs to show that the array.length is working as it should but there is a problem within the JS. 
Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That functions is a bit of a mess. Have a look at my approach:

- Put all 3 arrays into the same array, as they behave in the same way
- For each array (tier) do the same thing for all players
- If the team is not full, check if the random number is the right one, or the other team is full

  ```
  function randomFunction() {

  var allPlayers = [tier1, tier2, tier3];
  for( var ti = 0; ti < allPlayers.length; ti++){ //foreach tier
      for( var pi = 0; pi < allPlayers[ti].length; pi++) { //foreach player

          randomNumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);

          if( team1.length < 6 && (randomNumber1 <= 4 || team2.length == 6)) { //team1 is not full or team2 is full
              team1.push(allPlayers[ti][pi]);
          }
          else if( team2.length < 6 && (randomNumber1 > 4 || team1.length == 6)) { //team2 is not full or team1 is full
              team2.push(allPlayers[ti][pi]);
          }
      }

  }
  //I don't know what this bit is doing :D
  document.getElementById("test2").innerHTML = team1;
  document.getElementById("test3").innerHTML = team2;
  document.getElementById("team1").innerHTML = out1;
  }
  ```

Comment: I will give it a try soon and i will let you know :) i appreciate the time and effort but sadly I don't have the rep to vote up, the bit at the bottom is for testing its more relevant on jdFiddle i will take them out of the code on here

Comment: If it works, just mark it as accepted. Please note that both teams are limited to 6 players, so there are a few from Tier3 that won't be assigned

Comment: I'm happy to say it works :) thanks a lot, yeah I plan on only having 12 records in it when I'm using it I just overloaded it for testing purposes